# Located closest value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to located the closest value in a dataframe with user input.

```
Key  col1       col2
10   300        140
12   450        165
15   650        890
20   130        900
25   110        755
```

let's say i'm trying to input value 16. the value pandas should generate is

```
Key  col1   col2
15   650    890
```

I tried the `df.loc`, but that only works for specific values that are in the dataframe i guess.

Does anybody have an idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Is your index always sorted?

Comment: No, this an exemple the index (the key column) changes every time.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) with absolute values after subtract value:

```
val = 16
df = df.loc[[(df['Key'] - val).abs().idxmin()]]
print (df)
   Key  col1  col2
2   15   650   890
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `reindex` `nearest`

```
df=df.set_index(['Key']).reindex([16],method = 'nearest').reset_index()

     col1  col2
Key            
16    650   890
```